# salesforce external call to receive 50k+ records

Tags: salesforce, apex

We're looking to integrate some external systems and were envisioning ~50k-80k returned in a single call. Is this something a native call-out can handle, or do I need to chunk / batch process these records? I've done callouts to other systems, but not sure what salesforce can handle as far as receiving large data files from an external system. do i need to get a csv file, then submit to batch process from apex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use salesforce callout to process incoming response but you have to ensure that response you are receiving from a callout does not exceeds 6MB size for synchronous call and 12 MB if it is async.

You can not make a DML update on more than 10000 records in a single transaction. To process more than 10000 records you have to use either Future Methods or queuable interace.

You have call your future methods multiple times to process  small chunks of data i.e 10000 records or less.

A better solution would be to have inbound call from external system which upserts records.

Please mark it as a solution if it solves your problem.

Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

Use Bulk api jobs and process batches of 10,000 chunks, you can use [Jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#load-from-records) to create bulk api jobs and process those records more easily.